# Nginx location ignore doesn't work with upstream

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Why this:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://my_backend:3000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

works but this one:

```
location /api/ {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off valid=30s;
    set $upstream my_backend;
    proxy_pass http://$upstream:3000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

does not?

All I wanna do is proxy everything except `api` to backend...

Comment: Could you share api request example?

Comment: It's just simple GET `http://example.com/api/user/1` where `user` is route handled by NodeJS API.